# Prove that $\exists n \in \mathbb N: 2^p - 1|n^2 + n + 1$

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

> Let $p>2$ are prime number and $2^p - 1 $ prime number. Prove that exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n^2 + n + 1$ divisible by $2^p - 1$.

**I need an elementary proof of this fact**

Comment: How elementary, exactly?  Can we use the totient function?  Fermat's little theorem?  (Not sure if those are useful here, but what is the level?)

Comment: level is middle school

Comment: Can we use Fermat's little theorem

Comment: So no use of quadratic properties modulo primes ?

Comment: no use of quadratic properties modulo primes

Comment: Good luck.  :)  I'm not even sure I see a *non*-elementary proof of that fact.  But then, I haven't gone as deep into number theory as I might have.

Comment: @Wildcard An elementary proof does exist, but given the nature of its depth, I am not sure if it can be converted to middle school elementary.

Comment: I ask not to close this problem. I need it very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q=2^p-1$. As $\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$ is a finite field, it's multiplicative group is cyclic of order $q-1$. Let $a+q\Bbb Z$ be a generator. 
 Since $p$ is odd, $q=2^p-1\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so $q=3m+1$ for some $m$.
Then $(a^m)^3=a^{3m}=a^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod q$, but $a^m\not\equiv 1\pmod q$ (because $0<m<q-1$).

We conclude that for $n:=a^m$,
$$q\mid\frac{n^3-1}{n-1}=n^2+n+1.$$

Comment: Why $a^m \not \equiv 1 (\bmod q)$. If $m$ even and $a=q-1$ then $$a^m  \equiv 1 (\bmod q)$$